Change Charsequence array to String array or List<String> in Java
It should be simple but I couldn't find the easy one line answer. How can I change CharSequence[] to String[]. My goal is to change CharSequnce[]={"a","b","c"} to List<String>, but when I write Arrays.asList(a) android studio gives an error saying that Required type is List<String> but the Provided is List<CharSequence>. So it seems I need to change CharSequence array to String array first.
I also tried Arrays.asList(Arrays.toString(e)) but the output of printing the List will be [[a, ,b, c]], which is not what I want.

Notice that CharSequence[]={"a", "b", "c"} is assigning a right-hand String[] to CharSequence[], which begs the question: why are you using CharSequence to begin with? You could of course map these things: Arrays.stream(a).map(Object::toString).toList(), but that's seemingly wasteful compared to fixing your stored data to begin with.

Do you understand that a String is a CharSequence?  The String class implements the CharSequence interface.

@Rogue Thanks for your answer. This was just an example. I am using a CharSequence in this context (to get entries from a custom spinner): TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MultiSpinner); CharSequence[] entries = a.getTextArray(R.styleable.MultiSpinner_android_entries);

Iterate the array, transform each element to string, add transformed element to resulting list. You can use the Stream API (just one option):
CharSequence[] charSeqArr = //get data
List<String> result = Stream.of(charSeqArr)
            .map(CharSequence::toString)
            .toList();


Thanks. The only problem with this is that Android Studio requires API >= 34.
